# How to render error page in nuxt.js for SSR page rendering on page load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have default error layout page(`props: ['error']`) from the documentation.
But this page is rendering only when navigates by nuxt-link links.
Erors like

> "TypeError. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerWidth')"

on inital page load gives default error page (REQUEST DETAILS, HEADERS, COOKIES).

Example of page without custom error template layout in dev production. Same as in development mode, on initial page loading, Nuxt is rendering not layout props: ['error'] component.
[image]

Example of page without custom error template layout in dev mode
[image]

Comment: So far, the behaviors looks legit: moving to the error layout if there is something broken in the client side navigation. Not sure about the `default` error page tho. Can you please provide some visuals?

Comment: Yes. But if the SSR fails(for example when in view template {{window.innerWidth}}), nuxt send error page without layout error page.

Comment: Yeah, because it's not a routing issue. Seems legit.
Not sure about the error page but a way would be to safe-guard the error of `innerWidth` here in the first place.

Comment: Also, this is the case for dev. What happens if you generate/build and run the project locally? Does it gives you the same error or does it uses the error layout?

Comment: So it is possible to display 500 error layout?

Comment: I'll check late with build then.

Comment: You could maybe somehow send the user to the error layout in case of a client-side error but as I told you, what is the point of this one? You should rather avoid it, than send him to the error layout. Also, please check it now, this way you're fixed on the actual behavior.

Comment: Hm. I'll try to avoid render error layout then.